# Why is there no effect when using return between parentheses in shell function?

Tags: bash, shell

For example

```
function fff(){
    true && (return)
    echo 1
}
fff
```

The output is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the `fff` reaches till its end  and that's why `1` is being printed. The point is that `return` is executed in a subshell as you have placed it inside `parenthesis`. You should have done

```
true && return
```

instead of

```
true && (return)
```

Anything placed inside `()` is executed using a subshell and after the commands in the subshell finishes the control is passed back to the function `fff` and the subsequent command `echo 1` is executed in this case.

Below script will give you the right output

```
#!/bin/bash
function fff(){
 true && return 255
echo 1
}
fff 
echo $? # Will give you 255 as output
```

Mind that return value greater than 255 will be wrapped around ie you will get  `(value modulo 255) - 1`. For example if you return `259` you will get `3` ie `(259%255)-1`.

Comment: @BigShield : Thankyou for accepting the answer. Also, see a bit of explanation I've just added.